# Stage3D Error #3632: AGAL linkage: Varying 1 is read in the fragment shader but not written to by the vertex shader

Tags: stage3d

I am a beginner in AGAL, I'm sure this is not complicated.

I have a vertex and fragment shader, for simply drawing a box with a texture without light effect, here is the code:

```
            vertexAssembly.assemble( Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,
            "m44 op, va0, vc0\n" + // pos to clipspace
            "mov v0, va1"  // copy uv
        );
        fragmentAssembly.assemble(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT,
            "tex ft1, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" +
            "mov oc, ft1"
        );
```

I also have AGAL code for a Box with no texture, just color, and with light effect, here is the code for the shaders:

```
        private const VERTEX_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
        "mov vt0, va0\n"+
        "m44 op, vt0, vc0\n"+
        "nrm vt1.xyz, va0.xyz\n"+
        "mov vt1.w, va0.w\n"+   
        "mov v1, vt1\n" +
        "mov v2, va1"

    private const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
        "dp3 ft1, fc2, v1 \n"+
        "neg ft1, ft1 \n"+
        "max ft1, ft1, fc0 \n"+
        "mul ft2, fc4, ft1 \n"+
        "mul ft2, ft2, fc3 \n"+
        "add oc, ft2, fc1";
```

Question is, how do I combine the 2 codes, I want a box model with texture map, to show with light effect.

I did this:

```
        private const VERTEX_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
        "m44 op, va0, vc0\n" + // pos to clipspace
        "mov v0, va1"  // copy uv
        //"mov vt0, va0\n"+
        //"m44 op, vt0, vc0\n"+
        "nrm vt1.xyz, va0.xyz\n"+
        "mov vt1.w, va0.w\n"+   
        "mov v1, vt1\n" +
        "mov v2, va1"

    private const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
        "tex ft1, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" +
        "mov oc, ft1 \n" + 
        "dp3 ft1, fc2, v1 \n"+
        "neg ft1, ft1 \n"+
        "max ft1, ft1, fc0 \n"+
        "mul ft2, fc4, ft1 \n"+
        "mul ft2, ft2, fc3 \n"+
        "add oc, ft2, fc1";
```

but it gives me an error:
"Error: Error #3632: AGAL linkage: Varying 1 is read in the fragment shader but not written to by the vertex shader.
    at flash.display3D::Program3D/upload()
    at Context3DExample/setupScene()
    at Context3DExample/contextCreated()"

I'm sure someone with experiance can solve this in 5 minutes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to concatenate a string, i.e.

```
"mov v0, va1"  // copy uv
"nrm vt1.xyz, va0.xyz\n"
```

should be

```
"mov v0, va1\n" +  // copy uv
"nrm vt1.xyz, va0.xyz\n"
```

Notice extra `\n` and `+` on the first line.

Comment: Thank you, now I don't get the error message and it works, I see the light effect, but I don't get the texture map, somehow a color is overwriting the texture. If I take out some of the code, and leave only first 2 lines of the code:  "tex ft1, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" +
   "mov oc, ft1"; I see the texture again, but the light effect is gone, what should I do?

Comment: I have't programmed in flash for ages so I don't 100% remember. Try this ```private const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
        "tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" +
        "dp3 ft1, fc2, v1 \n"+
        "neg ft1, ft1 \n"+
        "max ft1, ft1, fc0 \n"+
        "mul ft2, fc4, ft1 \n"+
        "mul ft2, ft2, fc3 \n"+
        "add ft3, ft2, fc1 \n" +
        "mul oc, ft0, ft3";``` But I see other problems, for example normal should be renormalized in pixel shader.

Comment: I used your code but the result is the same, could that be because of the normals problem? because if I use only the 2 lines of code  "tex ft1, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" + "mov oc, ft1"; I do see the texture, I think normals are another problems, they determine if the model will look smooth or not.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Can you tell me what are your fragment constants (`fc` register)?

Comment: renderContext.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 0, Vector.<Number>([0,0,0,0]));
   renderContext.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 1, Vector.<Number>([0,0,0,0]));
   renderContext.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 2, Vector.<Number>([p.x,p.y,p.z,1]));
   renderContext.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 3, Vector.<Number>([1, 1, 1, 1]));
   renderContext.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, 4, Vector.<Number>([0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1]) );

Comment: Try this `private const VERTEX_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
"m44 op, va0, vc0\n" +// pos to clipspace
"mov v0, va1\n" +// pass uv 
"mov v1, va0";// pas normal` for vertex shader.

Comment: And this and  and `private const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIGHT:String = 
"tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n"+// read from texture
"nrm ft1.xyz, v1.xyz\n"+// renormalize normal
"dp3 ft1, fc2.xyz, ft1.xyz \n"+// directional light contribution
"neg ft1, ft1 \n" +// negation because we have a vector "from" light
"max ft1, ft1, fc0 \n"+// clamp to [0, dot]
"mul ft1, ft1, fc3 \n"+// contribution from light
"mul ft1, ft1, ft0 \n"+// contribution from light + texture
"add oc, ft1, fc1";// final color as surface + ambient` for fragment shaders. I added comments sj you should figure if it not works.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried it, but the result stays the same, I can send you the the whole code if you have the time to look at it, is it possible to upload the whole code? it's a bit long.

Comment: here is a link to the code, if anyone is interested in taking a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_t4cDR6CFBRmpmaGd1cmdRWWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I took out one line:  "neg ft1, ft1 \n" + and now I can see the texture and you can see the effect of the normls, but it is dark.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here is the code (based on nikitablack answer bellow):

```
        private const VERTEX_SHADER_LIGHT:String = "" +

        "m44 op, va0, vc0\n" +// pos to clipspace
        "mov v0, va1\n" +// pass uv
        "mov v1, va0"; // pas normal for vertex shader. 


    private const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIGHT:String = "" +

    "tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>\n" + // read from texture
    "nrm ft1.xyz, v1.xyz\n" + // renormalize normal
    "dp3 ft1, fc2.xyz, ft1.xyz \n" + // directional light contribution
    //"neg ft1, ft1 \n" + // negation because we have a vector "from" light 
    "max ft1, ft1, fc0 \n"+ // clamp to [0, dot]
    "mul ft1, ft1, fc3 \n"+ // contribution from light
    "mul ft1, ft1, ft0 \n"+ // contribution from light + texture
    //"add oc, ft1, fc1"; // final color as surface + ambient
    "add oc, ft1, ft0"; // final color as surface + texture
```

I took out the "neg of ft1" no need to negate this verctor in my code it is OK as it is. and I didn't add the ambient color at the end, just the texture once again so it will become bright and clear, with just a bit of shading.